# Pass variable from php to python script and run os.system()

Tags: php, python, variables, os.system

I need to set the date and time of my raspberry pi with a php script.
After some research I use a php script to call a python script.
My datetime.php :

```
$date = '2015-09-05'; 

$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python/home/pi/datalogger/modules/sys/write_date.py ' . $date);

echo $output;

os.system("sudo date -s "+"'"+date_object+"'")
```

write_date.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    date=sys.argv[1]
    time='22:04'
    print(date) #for debug

    string_date=date+' '+time+':00'
    date_object2=datetime.strptime(string_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    date_object=date_object2.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S"+" UTC "+"%Y")
    os.system("sudo date -s "+"'"+date_object+"'")

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

When I refresh my datetime.php I got my date print, so the script works... the problem is that my date is not update. But if I run write_date.py my command line I can update the datetime of raspberry.

Comment: You're executing a shell command via Python, why not format the date object in PHP and run the same command via PHP? I guess I am unsure why you are going from PHP to Python to perform simple command. PHP can do it for you on the Pi.

Comment: debug your code somewhere after `string_date = date+' ' ... `. 
is this a typo, or you have a python code in your php script?

Comment: Twisty, could you give me an example?

Comment: marmeladze, I print date_object and works...

Answer (score 0):

An example of setting the date, via PHP, on a Linux based system (E.G. Raspberry Pi):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$dt = date("D M j G:i:s T Y", strtotime("2015-09-05 22:04"));
$output = shell_exec('sudo date -s "$dt"');
?>
```

Also `strptime()` and `strftime()` exist in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Digging a little deeper, you may need to allow your Web Server to execute `/bin/date` via an adjustment to `/etc/sudoers` file. Can add:

`apache <hostname> = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/date`

Confirm the `<hostname>` by running `cat /etc/hostname`. I suspect it is raspberry or raspberrypi. Change it to fit your device.

To then run, we make one minor change to the script before:

`$output = shell_exec('sudo /bin/date -s "$dt"');`

That should do it. Found this info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44865/change-server-date-using-php

Comment: Twisty, I've tried but the date fo my raspberry don't change.
Should I need to "active some sudo permissions"?

Comment: I suspect so. Just to confirm, the PHP page is running on the RPi, correct? If so the apache user or www-data may need permission to a specific location to run date.

Comment: This will help with the permissions: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44865/change-server-date-using-php